# Database Connectivity ASP.NET - PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, ado.net, connection-string

Am trying to run a C# application which fetches data from PostgreSQL database(8.4) and am using the PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider

This is my connection string

> string connString =
>   @"Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB
>   Provider;Data
>   Source=localhost;location=;User
>   ID=;password=;timeout=1000";

The error am getting is

> The 'PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider'
>   provider is not registered on the
>   local machine

Can anyone point out me where should I correct so as to get the connect to the database. By the way am using PGOLEDBLib.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a few different "pgoledb" libraries.  None appear to actually be named "pgoledblib", so this info may or may not apply to you.

The [most recently active](http://www.pgoledb.com/index.php) PGOLEDB has documented their connection string attributes [here](http://www.pgoledb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8); it appears they use a different Provider value -- "PGNP.1".

[Another provider](http://connectionstrings.com/Providers/pgoledb), which seems to have been [languishing since 2006](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/), has connection strings [here](http://connectionstrings.com/Providers/pgoledb); these are in line with the earlier suggestions from OrbMan.

Of course, you may find that paying nothing for such a provider leads to paying much in installation, configuration, and utilization headaches.  Towards easing such headaches, I offer a link to [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/)'s [options supporting ODBC, JDBC, and ADO.NET clients on many platforms](http://download.openlinksw.com/download/product_matrix.vsp?p=l_os&c=1&df=9).

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you're using the OLE DB provider? I believe the general idea is that you get better performance, and I think also functionality, if you use a native .net provider - e.g. http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/

Comment: I have used Npgsql and am aware of its functionality. I wanted to use the other providers, no particular reason to use the OLE DB provider. But from what I've read using OLE DB providers is a better option.

Comment: Fair enough. There are AFAIK multiple OLEDB adapters available for PostgreSQL though - make sure you don't pick the one that's basically stopped being developed. It may be that only proprietary options are available at this point - I'm not entirely sure. But the "pgoledb" one appears to be unmaintaned at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Step 1: Down load & install

[https://www.pgoledb.com/index.php/component/filecabinet/?task=download&cid[0]=15](https://www.pgoledb.com/index.php/component/filecabinet/?task=download&cid%5B0%5D=15)

Step 2: Restart PC.

Step 3: Set the connection string as below

```
Provider=PGNP.1;Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User ID=yyy;password=xxx
```

It should work as your expected

Answer (score 0):

Try using "PostgreSQL" or "PostgreSQL.1" for the *Provider* attribute.. If that does not work, you will probably need to re-install the driver.